# .each loop are not executed completely ... why ? ( code and log available )

Tags: javascript, jquery

var idd;

```
$.each(data, function (i, items) { //1st each
    $.each(items, function (j, item) { // 2nd each
        console.log("Field:" + j + " Value:" + item);

        if (j=="sha_id"){ idd=item; }

    });
    console.log("Items");
    console.log("ID:" + idd);

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        console.log("being inserted");
        console.log("ID Inserting:" + idd);
        //then some database insertion query
```

This is sample upper part script

Basically 1st .each will run 2 round and 2nd .each will run two round for each 1st .each

So in console log I expect to see 
field .... value 
field ..... value 
Items 
ID : 2 
being inserted 
ID Inserting : 2 
field .... value 
field ..... value 
Items 
ID : 3 
being inserted 
ID Inserting : 3

But what i am getting is this

field .... value 
field ..... value 
Items 
ID : 2 
field .... value 
field ..... value 
Items 
ID : 3 
being inserted 
ID Inserting : 3
being inserted 
ID Inserting : 3

Why my db.transaction  is not executed just after console.log("Items") at first as they are in the same loop. Is there any code error i should correct ?

Comment: Is your database transaction code an asynchronous call?

Comment: yes they are asynchronous :S http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/#dom-database-transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably `db.transaction` is asynchronous.

This means the `$.each` loops continue to run, and don't wait for `db.transaction` to complete.

When `db.transaction` is finally complete, the callback you gave it is invoked. This happens *(relatively)* long after the `$.each` loops have finished.

The moral of the story is that any code that should wait for the `db.transaction` to complete, must be invoked within the `db.transaction` callback you're passing.

Comment: ok understand it now .... btw can u hint me how could i modify my this code and invoke the double loops from that db.transaction ?  or atleast make it to wait :S

Comment: @cjmling: Well, you don't really want to make it wait. You just need to get accustomed to working with asynchronous code. Is there some reason you *need* it to wait?

Comment: hehe, i don't really want to make it to wait :S....actually its gonna be around 20-50 loops.. so i should not make it to wait for an android apps :S ... if they r different function then its easy to handle it ... but this double loops with asynchronous code in it, making me to think hard  :S

Comment: ok...got one idea. at the moment those asynchronous code will just use the variable in the loops and process which could mess up the thing *as there are delay..... so if i pass variables to the asynchronous code will they process only with the variable i passed...no matter at what time they process or how much delay there is ? .....or again calling the asynchronous code with new variable will mess the first call up as they might not yet finish processing ?   ******Hope u get it**** i'll try this in the morning :D .... Thanks

Comment: @cjmling: I don't know which variables you're talking about. You'll need to post a more complete code example. If there's one `db.transaction` per outer loop, then each callback to the transaction will have access to the proper `i` and `items` parameters from the outer loop.

Comment: @amnoiam: I added some more codes with variables to show the db.transaction callback is not being processed with the expected values. :S